# Mozilla reload API method doesn't work

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I try to reload a Web page using (JavaXPCOM):

```
nsIWebBrowser webBrowser = (nsIWebBrowser) browser
                        .getWebBrowser();
nsIWebNavigation webNavigation = (nsIWebNavigation) webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
try {
    nsISHistory sessionHistory = webNavigation.getSessionHistory();
    if (sessionHistory != null) {
        webNavigation = (nsIWebNavigation) sessionHistory.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
    }
} catch (XPCOMException e) {
}
webNavigation.reload(nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE);
```

But reload doesn't happen at all. I tried force it by using the following flags, but page doesn't refresh as well:

```
nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_PROXY|nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE
```

Anyone knows what can be the reason for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you going from `nsIWebNavigation` to `nsISHistory` only to get `nsIWebNavigation` back? Also, what is `browser`?

Comment: `browser` is SWT browser. Originally the code didn't contain try/catch block at all, but then I looked how Firefox implements Refresh button (`BrowserReloadWithFlags` in browser.js)

Comment: I see. `browser.js` explains that this is for frame handling - probably for the case where you've got the web navigation of a frame and want to reload the main document nevertheless (session history is shared between all frames). It shouldn't be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking Error Console for syntax errors? You seem to be trying to use C++ type casts in JavaScript. That cannot work.  Assuming that `browser` is a `<browser>` element, this should work:

```
browser.reload();
```

Or:

```
browser.reloadWithFlags(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_PROXY|Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser for documentation on the `<browser>` element.

**Edit**: Given that this is apparently using JavaXPCOM the code seems to be correct with the exception that the entire `try .. catch` block should be removed. The only flag should be `LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE` to make sure you don't get a cached response.

Comment: I'm using JavaXPCOM, actually.

Comment: @spektom: That would have been worth mentioning... Anyway, I found the newsgroup post you copied that code from.

Comment: @Wladimir, is the newsgroup post about the same issue?

Comment: @spektom: Doesn't look like it - somebody simply posted some Java code in response to a question on Firefox extensions. That was five years ago.

Comment: @spektom: I added an update to my answer with JavaXPCOM in mind.

Comment: @Wladimir, Removed the try/catch block completely, removed `LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_PROXY` flag - still doesn't work.